# HTML Inspect element changes layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been noticing some problems with chrome and the inspect element functionality.

When the page I'm currently developing loads, some elements are misplaced (The text in this case):
[image: Loaded page]

Whenever I right click and select inspect element on the container of the misplaced element:
[image: Inspect element]

The element gets then magically placed as it should be:
[image]

You may have noticed I'm using nvd3.js, however this has happened to me before, and without nvd3.js. I don't think it's a nvd3 problem (I may be wrong).
My question is: **Does the "inspect element" of chrome trigger some sort of recalculation of the layout?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've also seen many times while designing and this is not a problem so question is off-topic in my opinion....

Comment: you may open the inspector in not-attached view.

Comment: Like @Bhojendra-C-LinkNepal said. In this mode it can resize height of window and your js or something can react on that.

Comment: yes seems that you are using `.resize()` method and opening of inspector is triggering the resize event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Youre Using .resize() or css media queries and when you click inspect element and console window opens (fixed in bottom part of chrome) youre screen resizes and some media query or .resize() funcion affects text alignment

Comment: Ok, yes, I'm not using .resize() but resizing the screen manually also affects the view in the same way, so that is what changes the layout.